# log4j conflicting?

Tags: java, log4j, htmlunit

I have a htmlunit application and I turned off its logging by the following lines since it was printing way too many messages in the console which I don't need.

```
LogFactory.getFactory().setAttribute(
    "org.apache.commons.logging.Log",
    "org.apache.commons.logging.impl.NoOpLog");
java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit")
    .setLevel(Level.OFF);   
java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("org.apache.commons.httpclient")
    .setLevel(Level.OFF);
```

I then added the latest log4j jar to my project and configured it so I can have my own custom logging messages. But now everything from htmlunit also goes to my log file. How can I prevent this? I only want my own logging messages to go to the log file.

Comment: What does your log4j configuration look like?

Answer (score 0):

One important thing to understand about log4j is its concept of a 'logger hierarchy', and how this affects its settings. To quote the log4j documentation,

> A logger is said to be an ancestor of another logger if its name followed by a dot is a prefix of the descendant logger name. A logger
>   is said to be a parent of a child logger if there are no ancestors
>   between itself and the descendant logger.
>
> For example, the logger named "com.foo" is a parent of the logger
>   named "com.foo.Bar". Similarly, "java" is a parent of "java.util" and
>   an ancestor of "java.util.Vector". This naming scheme should be
>   familiar to most developers.

A logger inherits the settings of its parent, and the 'root logger' is always at the top of the hierarchy. Therefore to some extent you can treat the root logger as the 'default' logger settings, and you can then add to these settings for just the loggers contained in your code.

I don't know how to set this up in code, but here is what I would do using a log4j.properties file:

```
# Direct log messages to a log file
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File=logs/springapp.log
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=1MB
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=1
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ABSOLUTE} %5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n

# Direct log messages to console
log4j.appender.console=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.console.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.console.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.console.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ABSOLUTE} %5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n

# Root logger settings: by default only log messages at level "ERROR" and above 
# will be logged. These messages will be written to console
log4j.rootLogger=error, console

# All loggers with names starting with "org.somecompany.someproject"
# will log messages at all levels "DEBUG" and above.
# They will be written to file as well as console; writing to console
# is enabled since that setting is inherited from the root logger.
log4j.logger.org.somecompany.someproject=debug, file
```

Then, assuming that the logger of each class is named as the fully qualified name of that class, then simply replace "org.somecompany.someproject" in the above config with the root package name for the packages in your project, and that should give you the behaviour you want.

For more information, have a look at [the log4j documentation](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/manual.html).